# Replace values in pandas.DataFrame using MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

### What I want to do

- I have two `pandas.DataFrame`, `df1` and `df2`. Both have the same columns.
- All indices in `df2` are also found in `df1`, but there are some indices that only `df1` has.
- Rows with an index that is owned by both `df1` and `df2`, use rows of `df2`.
- Rows with an index that is owned only by `df1`, use rows of `df1`.

In short, "replaces values of `df1` with values of `df2` based on `MultiIndex`".

```
import pandas as pd

index_names = ['index1', 'index2']
columns = ['column1', 'column2']

data1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]] 
index1 = [['i1', 'i1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i2'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index1, names=index_names), columns=columns)
print(df1)
## OUTPUT
#               column1  column2
#index1 index2                  
#i1     A             1        2
#       B             2        3
#       C             3        4
#i2     B             4        5
#       C             5        6

data2 = [[11, 12], [12, 13]]
index2 = [['i2', 'i1'], ['C', 'C']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index2, names=index_names), columns=columns)
print(df2)
## OUTPUT
#               column1  column2
#index1 index2                  
#i2     C            11       12
#i1     C            12       13

## DO SOMETHING!

## EXPECTED OUTPUT
#               column1  column2
#index1 index2                  
#i1     A             1        2
#       B             2        3
#       C            12       13 # REPLACED!
#i2     B             4        5
#       C            11       12 # REPLACED!
```

### Environment

Python 3.10.5
Pandas 1.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direct assignment via `.loc` or a call to `.update`

```py
>>> df3 = df1.copy()
>>> df3.update(df2)
>>> df3
               column1  column2
index1 index2                  
i1     A           1.0      2.0
       B           2.0      3.0
       C          12.0     13.0
i2     B           4.0      5.0
       C          11.0     12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `pd.merge()`on `df2` and then fill the missing values from `df1` with `.fillna()`:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right', suffixes=('', '_df1')).fillna(df1).iloc[:,:2]
```

I assume that there is a typo in your question and it should be:

```
index2 = [['i2', 'i1'], ['C', 'C']]
```